# Exportpage OpenText

Tags: xml, export, opentext

I have to export a number of pages from OpenText, parse the data and then put it into a new system. The problem is, I can't find any documentation for the opentext export. 
I get lines like this:

```
<PGE PGE0="6B77310C0933482D982CB2C14167B620" PGE1="7826862325B54678B783EE09B4BF2202" PGE2="1002" PGE3="0" PGE4="1C9F9B62E132491B8017A4D94B78DD39" PGE5="0" PGE6="" PGE7="0" PGE8="1" PGE9="0" PGE10="0" PGE11="" PGE12="&lt;ATTRIBUTES projectvariantguid=&quot;1B7860D850D8422798A66922BB80162F&quot; /&gt;" />
```

I simply have no idea what PGE 1 to 12 is and it is hard to work with it like that. 
The other files don't really look better.
Does anyone here know where I could find a docu for this cms?

Comment: Which Open Text software is this about?

Comment: This is about the OpenText CMS system

Comment: there are at least four Open Text CMS i know of. Which one?

Comment: Oh sry, Open Text Document Management System.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little DOS script I wrote to help with file import and export.  It's DOS (yuk!), but it should help you determine how to export and import files.  I've transferred entire folders using this script.

```
@echo off

set OTCS_Path=/OTCS/llisapi.dll

echo This script will export a select OT node and it's children.
echo It will then import the node(s) to a target server.

set /p ExportServer=Enter the Export OT Server name: 
set /p DataID=Enter the node's Data ID: 

start "" "http://%ExportServer%/%OTCS_Path%/llisapi.dll?func=ll&objAction=XMLExport&objId=%DataID%&scope=sub&attributeinfo&nodeinfo&versioninfo=all&content=base64&permissions&extuserinfo"

::    scope=base|sub|one|<n>
::    versioninfo=all|<n>
::    content=base64|plain|cdata
::    nodeinfo&attributeinfo&
::    permissions&extuserinfo

echo Now save the XML as a file on the Import OT Server's host.
pause

set /p ImportServer=Enter the Import OT Server name: 
set /p ImportXML=Enter the export XML full path on the Import OT Server: 
set /p ImportFolderID=Enter the Data ID of the folder to import to: 

start "" "http://%ImportServer%/%OTCS_Path%?func=admin.XMLImport&filename=%ImportXML%&objID=%ImportFolderID%"
```

Comment: How does this handle authentication?